# Extract meta-description content using DOMdocument() & xpath in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to extract meta-description content, from pages & display in search-results. 
But, its displaying it like :

> content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."

Whereas I only want:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Any guess, whats wrong in my code?

CODE :

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTMLFile($page_path);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

  $body = $xpath->query('//meta[@name="description"]/@content');
  $page_title = @$doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
  $page_title = $page_title ? $page_title : $page_path;
  $page_body = html2text($doc->saveXml($body->item(0)));// this is meta-description, which i want

  Functions :

  function html2text($html)
  {
  $text = $html;
  static $search = array(
  '@<script.+?</script>@usi',  // Strip out javascript content
  '@<style.+?</style>@usi',    // Strip style content
  '@<!--.+?-->@us',            // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
  '@</?[a-z].*?\>@usi',         // Strip out HTML tags
  );
  $text = preg_replace($search, ' ', $text);
  /*
  * normalize common entities
  */
  $text = normalizeEntities($text);
  /*
  * decode other entities
  */
  $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
  /*
  * normalize possibly repeated newlines, tabs, spaces to spaces
  */
  $text = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $text);
  $text = trim($text);
  return $text;
  }


  /**
  * Replace encoded and double encoded entities to equivalent unicode character
  * @param string $text
  * @return string - the same as $text but without encoded entries
  * @access public
  */
  function normalizeEntities($text)
  {
  static $find = array();
  static $repl = array();
  if (!count($find)) {
  /*
  * build $find and $replace from map one time
  */
  $map = array(
  array('\'', 'apos', 39, 'x27'), // Apostrophe
  array('\'', '‘', 'lsquo', 8216, 'x2018'), // Open single quote
  array('\'', '’', 'rsquo', 8217, 'x2019'), // Close single quote
  array('"', '“', 'ldquo', 8220, 'x201C'), // Open double quotes
  array('"', '”', 'rdquo', 8221, 'x201D'), // Close double quotes
  array('\'', '‚', 'sbquo', 8218, 'x201A'), // Single low-9 quote
  array('"', '„', 'bdquo', 8222, 'x201E'), // Double low-9 quote
  array('\'', '′', 'prime', 8242, 'x2032'), // Prime/minutes/feet
  array('"', '″', 'Prime', 8243, 'x2033'), // Double prime/seconds/inches
  array(' ', 'nbsp', 160, 'xA0'), // Non-breaking space
  array('-', '‐', 8208, 'x2010'), // Hyphen
  array('-', '–', 'ndash', 8211, 150, 'x2013'), // En dash
  array('--', '—', 'mdash', 8212, 151, 'x2014'), // Em dash
  array(' ', ' ', 'ensp', 8194, 'x2002'), // En space
  array(' ', ' ', 'emsp', 8195, 'x2003'), // Em space
  array(' ', ' ', 'thinsp', 8201, 'x2009'), // Thin space
  array('*', '•', 'bull', 8226, 'x2022'), // Bullet
  array('*', '‣', 8227, 'x2023'), // Triangular bullet
  array('...', '…', 'hellip', 8230, 'x2026'), // Horizontal ellipsis
  array('°', 'deg', 176, 'xB0'), // Degree
  array('€', 'euro', 8364, 'x20AC'), // Euro
  array('¥', 'yen', 165, 'xA5'), // Yen
  array('£', 'pound', 163, 'xA3'), // British Pound
  array('©', 'copy', 169, 'xA9'), // Copyright Sign
  array('®', 'reg', 174, 'xAE'), // Registered Sign
  array('™', 'trade', 8482, 'x2122') // TM Sign
  );
  foreach ($map as $e) {
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($e); ++$i) {
  $code = $e[$i];
  if (is_int($code)) {
  // numeric entity
  $regex = "/&(amp;)?#0*$code;/";
  } elseif (preg_match('/^.$/u', $code)/* one unicode char*/) {
  // single character
  $regex = "/$code/u";
  } elseif (preg_match('/^x([0-9A-F]{2}){1,2}$/i', $code)) {
  // hex entity
  $regex = "/&(amp;)?#x0*" . substr($code, 1) . ";/i";
  } else {
  // named entity
  $regex = "/&(amp;)?$code;/";
  }
  $find[] = $regex;
  $repl[] = $e[0];
  }
  }
  }
  return preg_replace($find, $repl, $text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving an attribute node as XML. Don't! Just read its value.

Attribute nodes (DOMAttr) have a property value that returns the attribute value. The attribute value is a text value.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<meta name="description" content="Some description">
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$description = $xpath->evaluate('//meta[@name="description"]/@content')->item(0);
var_dump($description->value);
```

Output:

```
string(16) "Some description"
```

But Xpath can return the value directly as a string. Just cast the result (in Xpath). This will only work with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. `DOMXpath::query()` can only return node lists.

```
$description = $xpath->evaluate('string(//meta[@name="description"]/@content)');
var_dump($description);
```

Output:

```
string(16) "Some description"
```

It will work for other nodes, too. If you cast an element node (like `body`) only its text content will be returned, entities like `&copy;` will get decoded.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Some description">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some content &amp; entities &copy;</p>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$title = $xpath->evaluate('string(//head/title)');
$description = $xpath->evaluate('string(//meta[@name="description"]/@content)');
$content = $xpath->evaluate('string(//body)');

var_dump($title, $description, $content);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "The Title"
string(16) "Some description"
string(36) "
    Some content & entities ©
  "
```

Comment: I used - evaluate. Its still giving me content="Some description", whereas , i just need - Some description, by saying bye to content="" symbols

Comment: I imagine the original source you copied saved the `body` element as XML and used string functions, trying to unserialize it. This is not needed, just read the value as string.